# Why LibGDX build fails using jdk 14

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to build a Desktop LibGDX project but keep on running into this error.
When I try and open it in Intellij it does not get synced correctly. Previously I had problems with Gradle but after updating java it seems to have resolved that issue.

I am using jdk 14.

```
Generating app in C:\Users\John's Desktop\Desktop\test2
Executing 'C:\Users\John's Desktop\Desktop\test2/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: 

https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Change Gradle version to a newer version, like:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip
```

You may need Java 14.0.0-zulu to make it run, since I tried using Java 14.0.0-open,
which gave me:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  /tmp/libgdxvushu/dd5c1a65/liblwjgl64.so

Answer (score 0):

Solved It! I failed to realize LibGDX creates a gradle project and gradle currently is not compatable with java 14 so I downgraded to java 8 and it works.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solved it! Consider formatting your question's title to something like "Why does LibGDX fail to build with jdk 14?" so others having the same problem can benefit from your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

JDK12 works aswell.